# Typescript Declaration: T|null|undefined returns the type you passed in

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to improve the DefinitelyTyped definition for [a function in angular](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/c24825040e417ec028a56947e83275efc35a0934/angular/index.d.ts#L759). It currently looks like this:

```
<T>(array: T[], a_bunch_more_stuff): T[];
```

Using `strictNullChecks` this does not allow passing in, e.g., `T[]|undefined`. I checked angular's source, and it specifically checks for and allows `null` and `undefined`. In those cases it simply returns the first argument. This is the best way I can think of to update the `.d.ts` file:

```
<T>(array: T[], a_bunch_more_stuff): T[];
<T>(array: T[]|null, a_bunch_more_stuff): T[]|null;
<T>(array: T[]|undefined, a_bunch_more_stuff): T[]|undefined;
<T>(array: T[]|null|undefined, a_bunch_more_stuff): T[]|null|undefined;
```

This will keep the correct unions on the return value. For example, if we only used the last line and you passed in a `T[]|null`, the return value would be `T[]|null|undefined` which is too wide. Is there a more succinct way to express those four lines while keeping their nice behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can declare function returning exactly the same type as its first argument, and express constraints on the argument type using two generic parameters like this:

```
function x<T, Q extends T[] | null | undefined>(a: Q, ...args: any[]): Q {
    return a;
}

class C {

    a1: string[];

    a2: string[] | null;

    a3: string[] | undefined;

    a4: string[] | null | undefined;

    f() {

        // check all permutations

        this.a1 = x(this.a1);
        this.a2 = x(this.a2);
        this.a3 = x(this.a3);
        this.a4 = x(this.a4);

        this.a1 = x(this.a2);  // disallowed
        this.a1 = x(this.a3);  // disallowed
        this.a1 = x(this.a4);  // disallowed

        this.a2 = x(this.a1);
        this.a2 = x(this.a3);  // disallowed
        this.a2 = x(this.a4);  // disallowed

        this.a3 = x(this.a1);
        this.a3 = x(this.a2);  // disallowed
        this.a3 = x(this.a4);  // disallowed

        this.a4 = x(this.a1);
        this.a4 = x(this.a2);
        this.a4 = x(this.a3);
        this.a4 = x(this.a4);
    }
}
```

Note that with `strictNullChecks` this makes `T[] | undefined` incompatible with `T[] | null` which might be too strict for real code.

Comment: Sorry I missed this last night. Somehow I never saw a notification for it. I will get back to this next time I'm working on the project. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: This works well, thank you. It does have a drawback, though. The caller cannot supply the generic type like this anymore: `x<string>(this.a5)`. Instead they must supply both generic types, e.g. `x<string, string[] | null>(this.a5)`.